# Markdown not working with django-rest-framework

Tags: markdown, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building an API using django-rest-framework.

The samples (e.g. http://restframework.herokuapp.com/) have Markdown support for documentation.

How to activate this on my own project? It's not working out of the box, and i can't seem to find help for this on the website (on in the tutorial documentation).
I already have installed `markdown` with pip (v2.1.1).

Thank you,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hm, feel kinda stupid.

My code was :

```
class UserList(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Display all `users`.
    """
```

Working code should be:

```
class UserList(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
Display all `users`.
    """
```

(markdown string should not be indented)

Comment: My guess is that you didn't restart the django server after you installed `markdown`. There is no need for un-indent the code. It probably just worked because you saved the file, and this restart the django server.

Comment: Indented code worked for me too

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is install `markdown`, and then write markdown formatted docstrings.

If it's not working you might want to double check that you've installed markdown into the project virtualenv, and not globally.

Comment: Thanks, but no v_env here, `$ pip install djangorestframework && pip install markdown
Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework
Requirement already satisfied: markdown` ; but my doc is not formatted; I fear i'm missing something

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `markdown`:

   ```
   pip install markdown
   ```
2. Stop the Django server by pressing `Ctrl + c` on the terminal that is running
3. Start the Django server again: `python manage.py runserver`

Django notices changes in files inside the django project directory, but not when you install new packages. Thus, it is necessary to restart Django manually after installing markdown.